# Youtube Data API for PHP - Not getting any "publishAt" values

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I want to track my uploaded videos by there scheduled date for publishing. I do get the uploaded videos and filter them by **privacyStatus** "private" but I won't get any **publishAt** values.

What do I do wrong?!

```
    // Call the channels.list method to retrieve information about the
    // currently authenticated user's channel.
    $channelsResponse = $youtube->channels->listChannels('contentDetails', array( 'mine' => 'true'));

    $htmlBody = '';
    foreach ($channelsResponse['items'] as $channel) {
        // Extract the unique playlist ID that identifies the list of videos
        // uploaded to the channel, and then call the playlistItems.list method
        // to retrieve that list.
        $uploadsListId = $channel['contentDetails']['relatedPlaylists']['uploads'];

        $playlistItemsResponse = $youtube->playlistItems->listPlaylistItems('snippet', array(
            'playlistId' => $uploadsListId,
            'maxResults' => 50
        ));

        $htmlBody .= "<h3>Planned Videos</h3><ul>"; //Videos in list $uploadsListId
        foreach ($playlistItemsResponse['items'] as $playlistItem) {      

            $listResponse = $youtube->videos->listVideos('status', array('id' => $playlistItem['snippet']['resourceId']['videoId']));
            $video = $listResponse[0];
            $videoStatus = $video['status'];

            // Just print private videos
            if ($videoStatus->privacyStatus == 'private') {         
                $htmlBody .= sprintf('<li>%s (%s)</li>', $playlistItem['snippet']['title'], $videoStatus['publishAt']);
            }
        }
        $htmlBody .= '</ul>';
    }
```

Comment: To clarify, are you talking about videos that were scheduled to be published at a future date, and are now published? I don't think you shouldn't be able to get `publishAt` data in that case. What's your use case for tracking them by their scheduled date?

Comment: I want to set up something like a calendar-view of my scheduled videos. I upload my videos to my channel and schedule them to be published at a future date. These scheduled videos are the videos I want to track.
In my opinion I should have a "publishAt" date in that case - until they were published.

Comment: So you're able to get the list of these scheduled videos, but they don't have `publishAt` data? Do you remember if it was working previously?

Comment: Exactly. I get a list of these scheduled videos, but as you say, they don't have a "publishAt" date. I am able to get every other value such as "license" or "uploadStatus" but there is no data within the "publishAt" field. But there were definitely videos that were scheduled and "privacyStatus" "private".

Comment: Hmm, sounds like a bug then. You can file a ticket [here](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/list).

Comment: I created a ticket for this issue. Another user tested the availability through Googles API explorer and it did not work there either.

Ticket: https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=7447&q=publishAt&colspec=API%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Stars%20Summary

Comment: Seems to be working now.